# Ordered points in a Point Cloud using some map

Tags: c++

I'm looking *container* to order a points in a Point Cloud by it's 3D position.
Basically I need a map to order and find points(with some properties ej: RGB) by its position, (X first, then Y, and finally by Z).

The key position X,Y,Z is stored as `std::vector<int>`
And the values that I want to store is other `std::vector<int>`

I think the natural type to do this is a `std::map`

But I'm not sure how to build keys for that map.

And how get an `iterator` ordered by X,Y,Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first thing you ought to do is switch from storing your points as a `std::vector<int>` to a *class* with fixed-size storage; using a `std::vector` to always store a fixed number of values that is known at compile-time is overkill and introduces a significant per-point memory overhead with no compensating benefit.

Given that, here's how I would do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

class Point
{
public:
   Point() : x(0), y(0), z(0) {/* empty */}
   Point(int xa, int ya, int za) : x(xa), y(ya), z(za) {/* empty */}

   bool operator < (const Point & rhs) const
   {
      return (x < rhs.x) ||
             ((x == rhs.x) && (y < rhs.y)) ||
             ((x == rhs.x) && (y == rhs.y) && (z < rhs.z));
   }

   bool operator == (const Point & rhs) const
   {
      return (x == rhs.x) && (y == rhs.y) && (z == rhs.z);
   }

   int x, y, z;
};


int main(int, char **)
{
   std::map<Point, std::vector<int> > some_points;
   some_points[Point(1,2,3)] = std::vector<int>();
   some_points[Point(3,2,1)] = std::vector<int>();
   some_points[Point(1,3,2)] = std::vector<int>();

   for (std::map<Point, std::vector<int> >::iterator iter = some_points.begin(); iter != some_points.end(); iter++)
   {
      const Point & key = iter->first;
      const std::vector<int> & val = iter->second;
      std::cout << "x=" << key.x << " y=" << key.y << " z=" << key.z << " --> vector with " << val.size() << " elements" << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow!! That help me a lot!! Worked ok! You're right, I'll switch to fixed-size class for the key.